# Not returning a value for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a script the function "`hola ()`" that should return the value of 1 if the radio button value is 1. But for some reason when I try to get the return value in another function i never get it.

The form works perfectly.. the only issue is that it doesnt return the value

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?? thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function hola() {
        $("form[name=yN]").show("slow");
        $('input[type=radio]').click( function (){
            var opt = $(this).attr("value");

            if (opt == "1") {
                this.checked = false;
                $("form[name=yN]").hide("slow");
                return 1;
            }

            if (opt == 0) {
                $("p").html ("ok");
                this.checked = false;
            }
        }) 
    }

    $("#iForm").submit( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var user = $("input[name=username]").val();
        var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
        var dbName = $("input[name=dbName]").val();
        var server = $("input[name=server]").val(); 

        $.get("1.php", 
              {username: user, password: password, dbName: dbName, server: server },
              function(data){
                 if (data == "The table PAGE exists" || data == "The table SUBJECTS exists" || data == "The table USERS exists" ) {
                    // CALLING THE hola () function and expecting a return 
                    var opt = hola();
                    $("p").html(data + opt);
                 }
              }
        )
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<!-- Yes or No form -->
<form  name="yN" style= "display: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 6em">
<input type="radio" name="yN" value="1">yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="yN" value="0">no</input>
<button id=1 >click me!</button>
</form>

<!-- Login Form -->
<form id="iForm"  style= "display: show">
<label id="username" >Username</label>
<input id="username" name="username"/>
<label id="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" name="password" />
<label id="server" >Server</label>
<input id="server" name="server"/>
<label id="dbName" >dbName</label>
<input id="dbName" name="dbName"/>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<p> </p>
```

Comment: it's best to always use semicolons to terminate statements in javascript - you're missing them after each `})`. Javascript will try and add them in for you, but this can sometimes go a bit wrong and leave you with some tricky bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers cannot `return` values because they're called asynchronously*.

Your existing `hola()` function will return immediately and the `return` statements in the `click` handlers are only called much later, i.e. when the button is clicked.

My approach would be this, using jQuery deferred objects (jQuery 1.6+):

```
function hola() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    // show the popup confirm form
    ...

    $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        // determine return value
        ...

        // send it back to anything waiting for it
        def.resolve(retval);
    });

    // return a _promise_ to send back a value some time later
    return def.promise();
}

$.get("1.php", { ... }).done(function(data) {
    if (...) {
        hola().done(function(opt)) { // will be called when the promise is resolved
            $("p").html(data + opt);
        });
    }
});
```

If you prefer, instead of returning the `opt` value you could use `def.reject()` to indicate "non-acceptance" and then use a `.fail` handler to register a handler to be called for that condition.

Comment: Thank you for the long response :). I tried it and now i get nothing being displayed in the browser for some reason

Comment: @JonathanThurft well, this code isn't 100% complete - I've omitted lots of your own code.  If you're seeing nothing then the chances are you've made a syntax error somewhere.  Your browser console should reveal where.

Comment: I modified your reply to fit your code and my code together. but dunno where the error lies

Comment: @JonathanThurft are there no errors on your console?  I can assure you that the general approach is fine - I use code like this all the time.

Comment: I am sure your approach is great the console error is "ReferenceError: retval is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

def.resolve(retval);" EDIT: i corrected it and now it works :) all i needed to do is put the variable inside `def.resolve()` Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You return 1 only in the click function of the radiobutton.
If you want to have a function "hola" that returns 1 if the radiobutton is checked, you simply need something like this:

```
function hola() {
  return $("input:radio[name='yN']:checked").val();
}
```

Comment: that only returns the _current_ state of the checkbox.  It doesn't "wait" for the checkbox to be clicked before returning.

Comment: It seemed to me like the user only needed a function to check the current checkbox state when "$("#iForm").submit(..." is called.
Of course this is assuming that the remaining code is a little bit refactored, i.e. setting up the click event handlers for the radiobuttons(which should imho only handle the dom manipulation) outside of hola.

Comment: @gabtub the OP has a separate "confirm" form / box popping up before the final action is supposed to be taken.   The checkbox in question is on _that_ form, not the one that was just submitted.

Comment: Sry, my mistake. Considering this, Alnitak's solutions seems to be the best one.
A dirty alternative would be to just put all the code from the "iForm" submit event (except the preventDefault ofc) into the radiobutton event handlers and call "$("form[name=yN]").show("slow");" in the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

`hola` does not even have a return statement. That's the reason for its not returning anything (more precisely: returning `undefined` always).

A JavaScript `function` that does not contain a `return` statement at all or whose all `return` statements are within nested `function`s will never return anything but `undefined`.

Comment: the `if ()` has a `return` statement

Comment: @JonathanThurft that return statement is inside another function, the `click` event handler. It's a totally separate function; nothing will be returned from `hola`.

Comment: @Champ: not anymore // Jonathan: The return statement is contained in a nested function definition. Hence the nested function may return something. hola itself at no point returns anything and thus is not able to deliver a return value. Never.

Comment: Probably you should explain what you want to achieve? Do you want to react to the click event or do you want to react to the submit event?

Answer (score -1):

Your are tring to return the value from withing the click callback function. Move the return outside that:

```
function hola() {
    var result;

    $("form[name=yN]").show("slow");
    $('input[type=radio]').click( function (){
        var opt = $(this).attr("value");

        if (opt == "1") {
            this.checked = false;
            $("form[name=yN]").hide("slow");
            result = 1;
        }
        if (opt == 0) {
            $("p").html ("ok");
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that but still in the browser i get "undefined"

Comment: @JonathanThurft yup, because the final `return` line **doesn't wait for the click event**

Comment: The nested function is called only after the click event, but hola does not wait for the click event, as you only register the handler. Hence you essentially have var result; return result; which results in an undefined return value.

Comment: Yes I somehow missed that. @Alnitak's response looks like the best solution

Comment: @JonathanThurft you never really make Javascript code "wait", what you do is register a handler that will be invoked sometime later when something "interesting" happens.  The deferred code in my answer extends the definition of an "interesting" event to "here's a value for you".